# How to present info on two versions of the same data field in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm running a report that gives me the total of sales for a product line represented as product_line_value. I need to use this same report to run totals for combinations of product lines (if I were to create a report for each individual combination I'd be creating over 50 reports.)

So a report looking at the combined totals of product line A and product line B works just fine. However, I'm having trouble reflecting that information in the report. Other than looking at values in my table, there is nothing to say this report is a combination of product line A and product line B. (Remember, since I'm using the same report for over 50 combinations

I can't just simply title the report "Product Line A" and "Product Line B") 
I tried placing product_line_value in the page header or as a group header but this only show one product line on each page, even the page totaling both product lines.

Also, I need to print and file each report. So if I have a month where no sales occurred I still need to print and file that report. But the report contains no information on the parameters other than the dates. In case it gets misfiled it needs to say this is the report for product line A and product line B for the month of May instead of just the month.

Is there a way to set up the report so that both product lines appear at the top of the page regardless of whether or not there is any data to report for a time period or do I need to create over 50 individual reports?

So what I'm getting is:

Page 1 Header: Product A  
Page 1: Product A

Page 2 Header: Product B  
Page 2: Product B

Page 3 Header: Product B  
Page 3: Product A and B totals

What I want is the page header to be:

Page 1 Header: Product A + Product B  
Page 1: Product A

Page 2 Header: Product A + Product B  
Page 2: Product B

Page 3 Header: Product A + Product B  
Page 3: Product A and B totals

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sub reports to achive this type of functionality.

You didn't mention any dependency of your tables so I assume you have multiple tables and you link outer join to the tables where you get product details so that you get product names irrespective of whether present in table or not.

To get product details in page header use a sub report and just concatenate all products that you need to display and place it in page header.

Now in main report create a group that will display product A first then product B and then in report just sum Product A+ Product B

Comment: Thanks. I wound up just using a join